# How much optimization does Scala's pattern matcher perform?

Tags: scala, optimization, compiler-construction

Suppose I have a Scala `match` expression

```
foo match {
    case Bar(Some(x)) => /* do something */
    case Bar(None)    => /* do something else */
}
```

How much optimization does the compiler do when it compiles the expression? In particular, does it emit multiple calls to `Bar.unapply`, or does it make a single call and match multiple times on the result?

Answer (score 6):

You can check this yourself with a little code:

```
object Bar {
  def unapply(x: Int): Option[Option[Int]] = {
    println("Checking: " + x)
    Some(None)
  }
}

1 match {
  case Bar(Some(x)) => println("do something")
  case Bar(None)    => println("do something else")
}
```

When you run it, you get:

```
Checking: 1
do something else
```

So it looks like Scala is not doing multiple calls to `Bar.unapply` even though the code looks like there would be multiple calls.  This is good from the standpoint of efficiency, but you should probably avoid side-effects in your `unapply` methods that rely on them getting called multiple times per match-statement.

If you were worried about when the optimization happens and making it clear to the reader that the `unapply` is only being called once, you could split up the matches quite easily:

```
1 match {
  case Bar(y) => y match {
    case Some(x) => println("do something")
    case None    => println("do something else")
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the plan was to improve this for case classes in 2.10